# How to round off ten random numbers in array?

Tags: perl

Trying to generate ten numbers which are random and without decimal point.

`my @randoms = map { rand } (1..10)`

This code returns ten random numbers yet with decimal like 
0.218220758325518.

I want round off these numbers.

Need a help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[rand](http://p3rl.org/rand) can take a parameter that specifies the supremum of the generated numbers. Just call [int](http://p3rl.org/int) to truncate it:

```
my @randoms = map int rand 20, 1 .. 10;
```

It generates numbers in the range 0 .. 19.

Comment: You might want to explain what _supremum_ means for non-native English speakers, like both of us. :)

Comment: Supremum is a maths term, it's like the maximum, but it doesn't have to be part of the set, i.e. `rand 20` generates numbers `0 <= x < 20`.